# Find a between field $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq K\subseteq L$ with $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=2$.

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

My exercise is

(1) to justify whether the field $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and

(2) to find an element $z$ with $L=\mathbb{Q}(z)$ and a between field $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq K \subseteq L$ with $|K:\mathbb{Q}|=2$ and $K\neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $K\neq\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

The field $L$ is a splitting field of the polynomial $f=(X^2-2)(X^2+1)\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$, and $L$ is a Galois extension over $\mathbb{Q}$.

For (2), I've found an element $z=\sqrt{2}i$ which equals $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}i)$. How can I find $K$?

Comment: Your claim that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})$ is not quite right :) The left hand side has degree 4 but the right hand side has degree 2. Can you show this? :)

Comment: Your argument leading to $L/\Bbb{Q}$ being Galois is correct (a nitpicker teacher may want you to repeat the generic remark that separability is not an issue in char zero). For part 2 see Andreas Caranti's +1 answer.

Answer (score 1):

You $z$ is not OK, as $z^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Try $w = \sqrt{2} + i$ instead.

But then your $z$ is OK to give you $K = \mathbb{Q}(z)$ - please check that indeed $K\neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $K\neq\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Answer (score 1):

To prove $z=\sqrt 2+i$ is a primitive element of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt2,i)$, you have to check

a) it satisfies a quartic equation,

b) this quartic equation is irreducible in $\mathbf Q$.

You'll easily find $z$ is a root of $p(x)=x^4-2x^2+9$. We can't apply *Eisenstein criterion* here, so we have to do it by hand.
Indeed, with the *rational roots theorem* it's easy to check it has no root. Further, it can't be factored as a product of two quadratic polynomials. For if it  did, we might suppose it factors as the product of two  *monic* polynomials with integer coefficients, $x^2+ax+b$ and $x^2+a'x+b'$.

Write down the equations obtained by identification:
$$\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}a+a'&=0, &b+b'+aa'&=-2, \\a(b-b')&=0, &bb'&=9.\end{aligned}\end{cases}$$
Then

- either $a\neq 0$,which implies $\;a'=-a$ and  $b'=b$, hence $\;b^2=9$,  $\;b=\pm3$ and finally $\;2b-a^2=-2$, so $\;a^2=2(b+1)= 8\;$ or $\;-4$. Both are impossible.
- or $a=a'=0$. We obtain $\;b+b'=-2,\enspace bb'=9$. $b$ and $b'$ are the roots of the quadratic equation $\;t^2+2t+9=(t+1)^2+8$. However this equation has no real roots.

Comment: Actually, Eisenstein does apply to $p(x)=x^4-2x^2+9$. First you form $q(x)=p(x+1)=x^4+4x^3+4x^2+8$, and if you don’t see a generalization of Eisenstein that applies, write out $r(x)=\frac{x^4}8q(2/x)=x^4+2x^2+4x+2$.

Comment: Very clever! Which generalisation are you speaking of? Unless you mean applying Eisenstein after an *ad hoc* transformation?

Comment: The generalization is that if the Newton Polygon has only a single segment, and this has no integral points other than the two endpoints, then the polynomial is irreducible over the $p$-adic completion, and therefore over your original number field.

Comment: I didn't know this result. Do you have a reference? May be in Serre, *Local fields*?

Comment: I don’t see it as a “result”, more an “observation”.